# T-SQL concatenate an incremental row number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to increase the number by concatenating with some value.

for Ex:

```
declare @i int
select @i =1
select right('000' + convert(varchar(3),@i),3)
```

output is : `001`

if my `@i value` increases to 1005

then the output should be: `1005`

I know I can increase the number '0000' , but I want this `start with 3 digits` then if `@i value reach 1000` then `I want in 4 digits` like this `1000,1001,1002...`

is there any way to get this..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if the value gets to 10000?

Comment: yes, I still needs to increase..that is the problem for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @i < 1000 THEN RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@i),3)
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@i)
       END /* CASE */
```

Comment: Hi @Joe, thanks for the reply,,but if my values increases to 10000. I need to increase output as well. thanks

Comment: @user3583912 So essentially you want numbers that are 2 digits or less padded with leading zeroes to a length of 3 and all other values left as is?

Comment: Hi @Joe, yes your right. Is there any dynamic way to do it? Thanks

Comment: @user3583912: The code given above should still work then. Just adjust the size of the varchar in the ELSE as needed.